# Why one of the navmesh agents is not moving to the next waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are two navmesh agents in this example.
One of them is moving between the waypoints. The second one is reaching to the first waypoint and then stop there and never continue.

I'm using this script to generate both the navmesh agents and the waypoints :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    public int objectsAmount;
    public bool parent = true;
    public bool randomScale = false;
    public string tag;
    public string name;

    public Vector3 RandScaleMin;
    public Vector3 RandScaleMax;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;
    private GameObject clonedObject;
    private ObjectPool objectPool;

    public void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void ReleaseObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] allobj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag);
        for (var i = 0; i < allobj.Length; i++)
        {
            objectPool.ReturnInstance(allobj[i]);
            allobj[i].hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInHierarchy;
        }
        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        objectPool = new ObjectPool(prefab, objectsAmount);

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsAmount; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            var randScaleX = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.x, RandScaleMax.x);
            var randScaleY = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.y, RandScaleMax.y);
            var randScaleZ = Random.Range(RandScaleMin.z, RandScaleMax.z);
            var randVector3 = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            clonedObject = objectPool.GetInstance();

            if (randomScale == true)
                clonedObject.transform.localScale = randVector3;//new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            if (parent)
            {
                GameObject parent = GameObject.Find(name);
                clonedObject.transform.parent = parent.transform;
            }

            clonedObject.tag = tag;
            clonedObject.transform.position = new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ);
        }
    }
}
```

And on each navmesh agent I'm attaching this script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AgentControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points = new List<Transform>();
    public bool isInMeeting = false;
    public float threshold = 3f;
    public float strength = 5f;

    private float speed;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private NavMeshAgent[] agents;

    void Start()
    {
        agents = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<NavMeshAgent>();

        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        var agentsDestionations = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");

        for (int i = 0; i < agentsDestionations.Length; i++)
        {
            points.Add(agentsDestionations[i].transform);
        }
        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = true;
        agent.speed = Random.Range(10, 50);
        speed = agent.speed;

        GotoNextPoint();
    }

    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, agents[1].transform.position);
        if (dist < 5)
        {
            isInMeeting = true;
            agents[1].GetComponent<AgentControl>().isInMeeting = true;
            StartCoroutine(Meeting(agents[1]));
        }

        //Meeting();
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 2f)
        {
            if (isInMeeting == false)
                GotoNextPoint();
        }
    }

    private void Meeting()
    {

        //GameObject randomAgent = agents[Random.Range(0, agents.Length)];
        /*if (Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, agents[1].transform.position) <= threshold)
        {
            isInMeeting = true;
            StartCoroutine(Meeting(agents[1]));
        }*/

    }

    IEnumerator Meeting(NavMeshAgent Agent)
    {
        var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Agent.transform.position - transform.position);
        var str = Mathf.Min(strength * Time.deltaTime, 1);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, str);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        isInMeeting = false;
    }
}
```

You can ignore the Meeting part since I never turn it on enabled.

This is a screenshot of the Hierarchy while the game is running showing the Instantiate Agents script in the inspector :

[image: Instantiate Agents Inspector]

This screenshot is of the Instantiate Waypoints Inspector :

[image: Instantiate Waypoints Inspector]

The last screenshot showing the agent control script inspector :

[image: Agent Control Inspector]

And now both agents stopped at the first waypoint and never continue.
Sometimes one of them is continue moving between the waypoints and the other one is keep staying at the first waypoint.

I want them both to patrol between all the waypoints.

Comment: didnt understand why you only worried about meeting agent[1], not the rest of them.  Are they stopped because they met?

Comment: @BugFinder The meeting part didn't work fine. So I marked it off not to use it. I forgot to update the code in my question. In my code the meeting part in the Update is marked with */ and */